# How to check if String contains value ".5"?

Tags: java, string

`List<String> list` has value [Standard .5"]

I am doing

`if (list.contains(".5\"")) { do something }` - is returning false - not sure why

Comment: try looping through each value and then doing the if statement

Comment: Why should `List#contains` do a "partial check" of its items? The list itself doesn't really know/care about what it contains. It just checks if there is an element which satisfies the `equals` method with the passed object.

Comment: @Javaboy Take a look at my solution below.

Answer (score 2):

You have to check the items in the list not the list itself

```
for(String s : list) {
  if (s.contains(".5\"")) { do something }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `List.contains()` method does a `.equals()` comparison. Since the strings aren't an exact match you'll want to iterate through the list and check if the string contains `.5"`.

```
for(String s : list) {
  if (s.contains(".5\"")) 
  { 
    do something 
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 possibilities here.

1. Either you wanted to check a specific element in the list and see whether it contains ".5"":

   ```
   list.get(idx).contains(".5\"");
   ```

**Or**

2. You want to check the entire list of elements:

   ```
   for(String str : list)
       if(str.contains(".5\""));
           //do whatever..
   ```

---

The `contains()` you invoked is coming from `list`:

> `boolean contains(Object o)`
>
> ***Returns true if this list contains the specified element.***

So it will only be `true` if one of your String element is having a content of only `.5"`:

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
l.add(".5\"");
System.out.println(l.contains(".5\""));   //returns true
```

The above will return `true` which is not what you want, as it checks whether any of the element matches `.5"` entirely,